# Xcode not authentication issue via Git/Tfs

Tags: tfs, xcode7

Xcode 7 is not authenticating the GIT/TFS Credential.
It was working in the previous version of Xcode 7.

Comment: i'm using bitbucket and it's working fine in 7.3

Comment: @John, We are working with TFS , Do you have any idea about TFS Integration with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with Xcode7, many others also met this situation.

Try to use below workaround:

Switch on basic authentication in IIS on your TFS box.

or

> Go to Xcode->Preferences and under the accounts remove all the repos
>   you may have there.
>
> Close all your projects and then kill Xcode. Make sure to wait a
>   couple of seconds (we speculate this is needed to let Xcode kill
>   everything as one colleague here had to do it twice).
>
> Then restart Xcode and re-open your projects so that it re-adds all
>   the repos using the corrects credentials.

More detail info , please refer this link [XCode 7, git broken](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19545)